# Django related User Model - Permissions and Decorators

Tags: python, django, permissions, decorator, user-profile

i am a beginner to Django i am trying to use permissions to permit access to specific view functions via a decorator, for specific user types only. Right now i am totaly confused by all kinds of stuff i have read about and seam not to figure out how i should do this.
I have two different kinds of users let it be UserTypeONE and UserTypeTWO.
UserTypeONE and UserTypeTWO should have access to specific views only.
Here is my code:

myuserTypes.py

```
class UserTypeONE(models.Model): 
    lieOtO_User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    lie_SomeAttribute= models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text ='Name')

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('Can_View_MyShop', 'Can see Shop View'),)

class UserTypeTWO(models.Model): 
    lieOtO_User = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    lie_SomeOtherAttribute= models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text ='Name')

    class Meta:
        permissions = (('Can_View_Targets', 'Can see the Targets'),)
```

Here is what i am trying to do in my views.py

```
@login_required
@permission_required('UserTypeONE.Can_View_MyShop', raise_exception=True)
def MyShopView(request):
    #do something
```

i also tried

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.usertypeone.permission('Can_View_MyShop'))
```

As you guys can see i am an absolute beginner unfortunately all documentations and examples havent done me any good instead i am even more confused.
I would really appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `user_passes_test()` here since you specifically want to restrict specific views.

First, define a couple of functions that return `True` when you're dealing with a user who should be able to see your content. It looks like your `UserTypeOne` and `UserTypeTwo` models extend the base `User` model with a one-to-one relationship, so you can use `hasattr` to check if a given base user has one of those attributes:

```
def type_one_only(user):
    if hasattr (user, 'usertypeone'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def type_two_only(user):
    #same thing without if/else
    return hasattr(user, 'usertypetwo')
```

Now when you have a view that you want to restrict to one user type, you can add a `user_passes_test` decorator before it:

```
@user_passes_test(type_one_only, login_url='/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

`login_url` is where a user will be sent if they do not pass the test you've indicated.